# Prove that a 2N × 2N Hamiltonian matrix A satisfies JAJ = transpose(A)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am just getting familiar with Hamiltonian matrices and therefore it is a little hard for me to understand their properties. 
My question is to help me prove or disaprove the following:

*JAJ* = [image] , where

[image]

I know that J is skew-symmetric matrix, and what I was starting with is:

*JAJ = A* ( since [image] = A).

by definition of Hamiltonian matrix: A is Hamiltonian if and only if [image] *= JA,*

therefore

[image] *J = A,*

[image] [image] *J = A.*

and I am kind of stuck at this point, I don't know what other properties I can apply , please help

Comment: I downvoted your question because (a) you did not use LaTeX or MathJax and (b) you did not define $J$.

Comment: You're not telling us what $J$ means. The answer may depend on knowing that. Also, you seem to think $(JA)^t=J^tA^t$ which is, in general, false.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, that's my bad with not clearly defining J, yeah I know that J has format of [0 -I ; I 0] for some reason I thought you know that too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that $A$ is Hamiltonian if $(JA)^T = JA$. Since for matrices $X$ and $Y$ we have $(XY)^T = Y^TX^T$, $A$ is Hamiltonian if and only if $A^TJ^T = JA$. Now, $J^T = -J$, so the last equation is equivalent to $-A^TJ = JA$. Moreover, $J^2 = -I$, so $J^{-1} = -J$.  Thus, $A$ is Hamiltonian if and only if $A^TJ^{-1} = JA$, i.e., $A^T = JAJ$.

Comment: Where does $J^2=-I$ come from? Do you and Dan have a secret agreement on what $J$ means?

Comment: I know what it is, but I'm not sure if Dan knows. It is the block matrix $J = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -I\\I&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you @amsmath , I did not know about those properties, your proof makes it much clearer , I think my mistake also was that  I did not use properly the transposition theorem

Comment: @GerryMyerson In the context of symplectic geometry (which is related to the context of this question), $J$ is frequently used as a symbol for an [almost-complex structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_complex_manifold), so it is reasonable for someone to assume that $J^2=-I$. In the particular case of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, $J$ is frequently used as a notation for the standard complex structure (if $J$ is actually the matrix that is mentioned in comments or "$-J$" may depend on the conventions). This justifies why amsmath assumed that, but of course it should have been clarified by OP.

Comment: @Dan F. If you are content with my answer please check it as finished. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, thanks again for your help @amsmath. The question's closed.